# Allow only one device to access the server through SSH

Tags: linux, ssh

I have Linux server with SSH enabled and I want to allow only my mobile phone to access it from anywhere and any network.

I tried to make a Firewall rule to allow specific IP but the thing is my mobile's IP Changes continuously.

So what is the procedure to perform this task?

- I tried firewall rule to prevent all IPs.
- I tried Fail2ban to ban all IPs that enter wrong password but it
  blocks huge number of IPs which will affect system's performance.

Comment: Are you worried about failed attempts hurting your server performance? You must be getting a lot of them. If your mobile client supports it you could change the server port from 22 to some high obscure value. Not surefire but would cut down on automated garbage.

Comment: No not failed attempts but i am worried from blocking large number of IPs.
Changing port is a good idea but still have the same problem and others can know what ports i uses.
I want to block all other devices except this mobile but without using IP rule.

Comment: If you have a strong password or generate a key pair (preferred) and use that it is very secure so others attempting to access have pretty much zero chance of getting in. The traffic only affects server load at that point so I'm not sure what blocking IPs would do other than slightly reduce load. Maybe you don't want other people to be aware SSH is running? Search for "port knocking" which could help hide SSH if you change the port. There are port knocking clients for ios and android as well.

Comment: Do not use passwords. Use SSH keys to authenticate. And put your key on a USB stick and use a USB-OTG adapter.

Answer (score -1):

It'll be difficult unless you figure out a way to expose an api via https from your sever that can change deny/allow rule when your mobile IP changes. I personally don't know of anything like that... I just use openvpn for my mobile to connect and I ssh to remote systems.